# insert text into an sceditor textarea from a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all I am very new to javascript and jquery so bear with me, I am trying to make a multi-quote system for my sites comments system. SCEditor is this btw: http://www.sceditor.com/

I have this code

```
<script>
function insert_quote(quote_id)
{
    var text = Document.getElementById(quote_id).innerHTML;
    $('textarea').sceditor('instance').insert(text);
}
</script>
```

And this:

```
<td valign="top">
    <div id="{:comment_id}" class="forumpost">{:text}</div><br />
    <a onclick="insert_quote({:comment_id});">Multi Quote Test</a>
</td>
```

Where {:comment_id} would be the id of the comment from the database.

It doesn't work since i'm obviously doing something stupidly wrong, can someone help?

Comment: Change `Document` to `document`.

Comment: Yes that makes it work but i need to figure out how to get it to insert the bbcode rather than plain html :(

Answer (score 0):

First you didn't put quote to `(quote_id)` and `document` have not uppercase so it is why it doesn't work. But it would be preferable do to all by jQuery and remove the "onclick" attribute like this.

**JS**

```
$('.comment').on('click', function() {
        var text = $(this).prev('.forumpost').text();
        $('textarea').sceditor('instance').insert(text);
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<td valign="top">
        <div id="{:comment_id}" class="forumpost">{:text}</div><br />
        <a class="comment">Multi Quote Test</a>
</td>
```

**EDIT**

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QTJsP/5/) to see it in action.